# Typographic weight names

Tags: typography

Sometimes letters in mathematics are printed in special fonts (e.g., fraktur p for a prime ideal or script F for a sheaf). If I had a script X and wanted to literally say "script X" and not just "X", is it correct to say икс рукописное?

For context, I learned from several Russian mathematicians, who had been educated in Russia at least through the undergraduate degree, that the first four LaTeX typefaces in the list

[image]

are pronounced as follows:

- "bold X" is икс жирное,
- "gothic X" is икс готическое,
- "italic X" is икс курсивное
- "calligraphic X" is икс калиграфическое.

The last example, "script X", is one I did not get a consistent answer about and that is the one I am asking about now. I am specifically interested in a translation where the term "script" is treated as an adjective (the same way I wrote the other font translations above), so Russian translations where the instrumental case of the font name is used, which would correspond essentially to "X written by means of script", are not the type of translation I'm looking for.

Comment: btw, this has nothing to do with fonts or with math. It's purely a typography question dealing in *weights*. Like with other languages, there are plenty of uses for the different weights apart from math.

Comment: @Vitaly: I agree the question I ask can be considered with a broader scope, but in case there were different conventions about how letters in various fonts are described in math and in other areas, I wanted to know the way it goes in math since that is the case of interest to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIU it depends on what exactly do you need to highlight:

1. You want to specify the typographic visual representation of x. In this case you need to emphasize font details. For example:

   - икс курсивом (literally: x in italic font)
2. You want listeners to understand the difference between *x* and x. I have several suggestions here:

   - икс наклонный (literally: inclined x)
   - икс рукописный (literally: handwritten x)
   - икс косой (literally: oblique x)

Comment: I might be opening up a can of worms here, but I was told by several Russian mathematicians that all Latin and Greek letter names are considered to be neuter in Russian mathematics (there was some uncertainty on delta, but not on the others). So I am intrigued that you write your adjectives as if икс is masculine. Do the phrases икс наклонное or икс рукописное sound strange to you?

Comment: No, they don't. I always treated икс as masculine, but I've heard phrases like `икс большое`. Orthographic dictionary treats `икс` as masculine. I don't think it's wrong to treat variables as neutral, by analogy with `неизвестное`. Also many times I've heard people treating `альфа` and `омега` as feminine.

Comment: @KCd It's very much a question of the specific use. If you're referring to the actual letter itself, then neuter is pretty common among pedants and teachers :). But a person  talking about a variable that actually represents something would never say "между ними большое дельта", only большая дельта (the delta [math. difference] between them is large).

Answer (score 2):

In Russian math books Latin letters in formulae are set off in italics by default. It's a standard. So usually there is no need to emphasize this fact. However, if it's printed it's not `рукописный` (handwritten), it's `курсив` (italics).

Comment: Yep. And instead of different typefaces greek and even hebrew letters are used.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `X` which was handwritten or any handwritten text, it would rather be `икс прописной` or `икс прописью`.

Comment: That sounds more like "capital x" to me.

Comment: Capital is a type of LETTER CASE, which is the distinction between the larger majuscule (capital, caps, upper case, upper-case, or uppercase) and smaller minuscule (lower-case, etc.) letters. Here the question was about special FONTS rather than LETTER CASE.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. "Прописной" means "capital", so instead of communicating "script x" you would be communicating "X". See the problem?

Comment: As far as I see it, "capital" and "Прописной" are completely different things, like I described in the previous comment. Maybe I didn't understand the initial question but unfortunately I don't see the problem. Sorry. икс прописной means X which was handwritten, or in your case, one which was typed used handwriting like font..

Comment: Perhaps this will demonstrate: [translation](http://translate.google.com/#ru|en|прописной), [definition](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Прописные_буквы).

Comment: Yes, according to the wiki,  прописные буквы has two meanings. I was not aware of the second one (which also mean that it can be used for capitals).

Comment: Perhaps "Икс прописью" would be more clear?

Comment: @xyzman I agree.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify that I am looking for a translation using an adjective as "script", so икс прописью isn't the type of translation I am looking for. See the new last paragraph of my question.

Comment: On a separate note, as with the answer by default locale I see that you're treating икс as if it is masculine, but Russian mathematicians I spoke to told me that Latin and Greek variable names are (except maybe delta) always considered to have the neuter case, and actually to be indeclinable except, apparently, that x and y can be declined in the dative case. For instance, f(x) is эф от икс, not эф от икса.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this could be called "рукописное", but I've not seen such typeface was used.

BTW
Correct name for typographic characteristic like "X written by means of italic" would be "курсивное начертание" or  "Икс в курсивном начертании".

Most people are not professionals in typography, though and use simpler form like "икс курсивом".